# C#: Help polishing string parsing

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

One of the things I really value from this community is learning ways to do things in two lines that would normally take me twenty.  In that spirit, I've done my best to take some string parsing down from about a dozen lines to three.  But I feel like there's someone out there who wants to show me how this is actually a mess.  Just for my own edification, is there a cleaner way to do the following?  Could it all be done in one line?

```
string getThis = "<add key=\"messageFilter\" value=\"";
string subStr = strFile.Substring(strFile.IndexOf(getThis) + getThis.Length);
string[] igPhrases = subStr.Substring(0, subStr.IndexOf(";\"")).Split(';');
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the quick responses!  Really helpful examples AND good advice with a minimum of snark. :) Fewer lines is not the same thing as clean and elegant, and reducing lines may actually make the code worse.

Let me rephrase the question.

I've got an XML doc that has the following line: `<add key="messageFilter" value="Out of Office AutoReply;Automatic reply;"/>`.  This doc tells our automated ticketing system not to create tickets from emails that have those phrases in the subject line.  Otherwise, we get an endless loop.

I'm working on a small program that will list phrases already included, and then allow users to add new phrases.  If we notice that a new autoreply message is starting to loop through the system, we need to be able to add the language of that message to the filter.

I don't work a lot with XML.  I like Sperske's solution, but I don't know how to make it dynamic.  In other words, I can't put the value in my code.  I need to find the key "messageFilter" and then get all the values associated with that key.

What I've done works, but it seems a little cumbersome.  Is there a more straightforward way to get the key values?  And to add a new one?

Comment: less lines doesnt mean cleaner code

Comment: In my not so humble opinion, I don't think you should aspire to write as few lines of code as possible.  I think you should aspire to write clean, clear, easily understood, well-designed code.

Comment: Is that just a part of something bigger? Like parsing `XML` file? Is so - please let us know, there are way better ways for parsing those.

Comment: Well, that looks like XML... why don't you use an XML API to parse it?

Comment: There are three criteria for writing code...Short, Readable, and Efficient.  pick two.  A Classic Triangle :-)

Comment: @Nevyn Love it!  Great way to think about how to strike the best balance possible, recognizing that there will have to be sacrifices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly different one liner (split for readability):

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument
  .Parse("<add key='messageFilter' value='AttrValue'/>")
  .Root
  .Attribute("value")
  .Value
```

Outputs:

```
AttrValue
```

To address the updated question you could turn all of your `<add>` nodes into a dictionary (borrowing from Pako's excellent answer, and using a slightly longer string):

```
var keys = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument
  .Parse("<keys><add key='messageFilter' value='AttrValue'/><add key='userFilter' value='AttrValueUser'/></keys>")
  .Descendants("add")
  .ToDictionary(r => r.Attribute("key").Value, r => r.Attribute("value").Value);
```

This lets you access your keys like so:

```
keys["messageFilter"] == "AttrValue"
keys["userFilter"] == "AttrValueUser"
```

Comment: Now as for efficient... well let's just say you might need to give up that "one line" rule

Comment: +1 just suggest to edit that 'in two lines' (wrapped) - so it's easier on the eyes :)

Comment: Much more elegant!  Thanks @JasonSperske!  I've updated my question.  I actually need something more dynamic, as the key value is variable.

Comment: @tmoore82, I tried to build on Pako's answer and add that dynamic ability your updated question is after, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It has been answered already, but for future readers - if you want to parse bigger XML, with root and many `add` nodes, you may need to use something slightly different.

```
string xmlPart = "<add key=\"messageFilter\" value=\"\" />";
string xml = "<root>" + xmlPart + "</root>";
var x = XDocument.Parse(xmlPart, LoadOptions.None);

var attributes1 = x.Descendants("add").Select(n => n.Attributes());
var attributes2 = x.Descendants("add").SelectMany(n => n.Attributes());
```

This will get you `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XAttribute>>` (see `attributes1`) or `IEnumerable<XAttribue>` (see `attributes2`). Second option will simply flatten results - all attributes will be held in one collection, no matter from which node they came from.
Of course nothing stops you to filter `XAttributes` by name or some other criteria - it all up to you!

Comment: +1 I tried to adapt this answer in mine (hopefully I've added more), but still think you deserve credit for responding with this first and in depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

one ugly line:

```
string[] igPhrases = strFile.Substring(strFile.IndexOf(getThis) + ("<add key=\"messageFilter\" value=\"").Length).Substring(0, strFile.Substring(strFile.IndexOf("<add key=\"messageFilter\" value=\"") + ("<add key=\"messageFilter\" value=\"").Length).IndexOf(";\"")).Split(';');
```

Comment: +1 for doing what tmoore82 asked for, -1 for adding to an approach that seems misguided :P

Comment: i would hate to debug this.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted!  With the advice I've been given, I'll probably go another way, but it's really helpful to see what I was aiming for, Artem.